# Containers with Azure web apps and APIs

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, containers, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to get my head around the usefulness of containers in certain scenarios to see whether we as an organisation would benefit from their use.

We currently have multi tier applications in Azure using web applications and API objects. The infrastructure is replicated across QA, STG and PRD environments with development carried out in local environments on developer workstations.

Infrastructure code and application code is stored in Git repos and deployed via CI/CD pipelines.

I'm trying to figure out if there would be any benefit to using containers in this scenario and I'm struggling to see what containers would bring to the table in this scenario.

Any comments and experiences from those using similar technology stacks would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question especially without having more specifics on the architecture of your current applications in Azure.   Are you using the App Services PaaS service for your web applications?   Same question for your API objects?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are using App Services PaaS for both web applications and API's. 

I guess my real question is why would anyone want / need to deploy containers into web application? From looking around on the web I can see that people are doing this but I don't understand the benefits. 

I'm also interested in the benefits containers could deliver in our local dev environments. It seems that we could create containers for each of our application components (API's, web aps, DBs) and have end to end environments locally but would this not be too resource intensive surely!?

Comment: The reason containers on web application (App Services) has appeal is that you can stipulate your own OS distro and your desired framework, tooling, version & etc.   So if you want to run Flask version X on Alpine Linux but still allow it to be auto-scaled and etc... you can.  You are taking on the container config responsibility so you can have your own desired web platform stack.  [Those comments are specific to the appeal of Azure App Services running containers]

Comment: Container benefits for local dev environments:   Consistency, Density (vs VMs), Multi-stage builds, Layering, Offline execution for early builds, testing, etc.    On the resource intensive side it depends on your platform as Linux OS/Webserver/Web Platforms can be containerized pretty effectively so they are small in size and resource needs.  Windows containers are larger in size and can require more resources but are still smaller than running a local VM.

Comment: All the above being said you raise a valid observation that is prevalent.  We spend a lot of time on getting containers built, automated, evaluated, secured, networked and orchestrated.  (like we did with VMs in the past)  That time is not value building to the business.  So if you can move to a PaaS and/or Serverless application architecture/model you can further reduce your "technical debt" and focus on business value.   The counter argument of course is the OS/framework control you give up when you move to those delivery vehicles.